# Which character does this "stunt" lightsaber belong to? It appeared in Star Wars Ep II

Tags: star-wars, lightsaber, attack-of-the-clones, object-identification

**Does anyone know which character this stunt lightsaber belonged to in Star Wars: Attack of the Clones?**

A bit of background: I worked on the film for nearly 12 months. Was generously gifted the lightsaber below at the end of principal photography. Forgot I had it. Thought I'd look into it before dumping it back into the box. It has a green screw on saber (which special effects were of course then added to)

[image: lightsaber]

Comment: *When* or *where* in the film does it appear? That will help people get you the answer.

Comment: @TimPederick - It appears in the jedi fight scene on Geonosis. Here's a pic of the actress holding it; https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/0b/49/57/0b4957b3f97e8b693c5783ce3bfcf49c.jpg

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lacunas_Subartuk's_lightsaber

Comment: You people are great. We have an answer. @Valorum thank you kindly. Everyone on here, thank you for your help. I 'worked' on the film for nearly 12 months. Was generously gifted this at the end of principal photography. Forgot I had it. Thought I'd look into it before dumping it back into the box. It has a green screw on saber (which special effects were of course then added to). I've no idea what cosplay is, but I wish it well, as I wish to all of you too. A great community.

Comment: @JDoe - If you did choose to sell it, you could earn some serious money doing so. A "screen-used" lightsaber with a known provenance is something that many fans would *dearly love* to get their hands on.

Comment: I've edited in the details from your comment. It adds background and dramatically improves the question.

Comment: @Valorum You've made my words sing now! Thank you. You made mention that many fans might be interested in getting their hands on it. A couple of other industry friends have mentioned that before, but as soon as they mention it, I'd forgotten all about it. I would know where to begin in getting word out there to fans. Would you have any wisdom you could impart on how I might hypothetically do that?

Comment: @JDoe - Your best bet is probably to contact companies like [Propstore](http://www.propstore.com) or [Yourprops](https://www.yourprops.com). Christies and Sotheby's (and other auction houses) often have 'themed collections' including scifi stuff. If you post it onto ebay (and make sure it gets some publicity on sites like theforce.net and starwarsnewsnet.com) you'll probably get quite a few bidders interested. You might want to ask someone better equipped than I for an evaluation, like http://theswca.com as they can help you put together a proper provenance (which will double the value).

Comment: [This](https://www.liveauctioneers.com/item/12084552_star-wars-the-phantom-menace-stunt-lightsaber), for example went from just over $12,000 at Liveauctioneers. It's a much more valuable piece since it was *extensively* screen-used by a major actor in the film but it should give you an idea how to market it

Comment: And don't forget to nip into chat to mention if/when you put it up for auction. Spamming isn't allowed, but I think you could be forgiven for putting up a link and chatting about it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange, and thanks for this question! It's always great to get people on this site who've actually been involved in the making of the film. Since these comments have gone slightly off-topic, I've [moved them to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41336/discussion-on-question-by-j-doe-which-character-does-this-stunt-lightsaber-bel), where you now have just enough rep to participate.

Comment: @JDoe - Hoping you are still plugged into these updates. There are a number of additional Jedi characters, like Plo Koon who used this saber style as well. I have been collecting and working with original Star Wars props in the collecting community for years and would love the opportunity to speak with you further. Hope to hear from you.

Answer (score 16):

### It could be Jedi Master Luminara Unduli's lightsaber.

This is a scan from [The Visual Dictionary of Star Wars, Episode II - Attack of the Clones.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0789485885)

[image: image from visual dictionary]

The caption states that her lightsaber follows a *"common lightsaber design"*.

In fact, the same page shows Plo Koon's lightsaber, which is very similar:

[image: Plo Koon's lighsaber]

The main difference is in the color of the *"radiator casing"*, which is golden in Luminara Unduli's saber and silver/steel coloured in Plo Koon's; moreover, Plo Koon's lightsaber shows blue markings at the opposite end.

This image, a particular taken from the image gallery in her [official databank page](http://www.starwars.com/databank/luminara-unduli), shows her some years later, in the Clone Wars animated series, using the same lightsaber:

[image: particular from databank image]

**There is a non-matching detail**: the color of the round buttons, which are green and grey in the question image and red and green in these images. However, this could be due to degradation of the paint on the prop, especially as the buttons would be right in the grip of the person holding the lightsaber.

Additional images showing the lightsaber (click to enlarge), found by our most excellent chancellor @Valorum:

[image: Luminara Unduli and her padawan Bariss Offee]
[image: image with signature of actress Mary Oyaya]

Comment: Ahem; http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2879/9542669826_cbffa1fda9.jpg

Comment: Could this be part of a cosplay project?

Comment: Fun fact: TIL that in the Italian edition of the visual dictionary the *blade length adjust* button became a *charge connector*. I guess the book was *not* translated by a protocol droid knowing thousands of languages.

Answer (score 5):

This lightsaber style was used by a variety of Jedi in Attack of the Clones (and was used in all three prequels, although only on a belt in Ep.1). Your stunt prop style saw a lot of use from a number of background Jedi on Geonosis in Ep.2, including from Jedi named Jedi such as Luminary Unduli and Plo Koon.

Of the original six saber designs created during pre-production on Episode 1, two were hand picked by Ewan and Liam, and the others became the basically the same 4 sabers every Jedi uses in the prequels aside from the Anakin and new Mace designs made for Ep.2. I am not counting Sith sabers, nor the new Anakin and Obi-Wan from Ep.3.  But for everyone else you see wielding a saber in Episode 2 and 3...they are using these original saber designs. So, your particular stunt saber could have been used by any number of background stunt jedi or one of the more well known Jedi Council jedi. It's a great hilt design that shares some of the same detailing found on the emitter end of Darth Maul's lightsaber prop.

[image: Original Six Hilt Designs]

Attached is another stunt example of this prop that I have had access to in the past.[image: Stunt Saber]